# Resources NotFoundException getColor() that uses colorAccent attribute

Tags: android, exception

Why can't this color be resolved programmatically:

Definition of the style.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

Definition of colors.xml:

```
<color name="button_color">?attr/colorAccent</color>
```

Source:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color);
```

Throws the following exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f07001b type #0x2 is not valid
at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:752)
...
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a library project and that my intention is to use the accent color of the parent project as the default color for the button but also allow that button style to be overridden. Really what I'd like to know is why this attribute can't get resolved at runtime?

Comment: Did you eve manage to solve this? I seem to be running into a similar problem...

Answer (score 3):

Change:

Definition of the `style.xml`:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/button_color</item>
</style>
```

Definition of colors.xml:

```
<color name="button_color">#ff0000</color>
```

Source:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] { android.R.attr.colorAccent });
int color = typedArray.getColor(0, 0);
```

This works for me. You might be able to replace android.R.attr.colorAccent with your color resource.